# Value from a url using php

Tags: php, youtube

I want to extract a value from the url for example the url is

http://www.youtube.com/watch?**v=N22qGmYIUVU**&feature=g-logo

i would need to have the value of v from the url using php. I understand it needs to be done using regex, but me not so good at it, I have checked the other related questions but i found issues with the way they resolved.

for ex this regex - /http\://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=([\w-]{11})/

restricts the value of v to 11 i do not want that, basically if it encounters a "#" or a "&" or any delimiter the value of v should be terminated and extracted.

the value of v could be of any length

Please help!

Comment: Do you want value of v from URL or you want to generate value of v in URL?

Comment: please use the search, your question is a duplicate.

Comment: yes it is in a way duplicate, and i have mentioned already that it is, none of the answers were satisfactory , that's why posted it again :(

Comment: yes i want the value of v from the url, basically i take this url as an input and identify all the variables associated with it for another funcitonality

Comment: you do not need regex for that. And you should not use regex for it if regex is complicated for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more fool proof way than using regex.

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N22qGmYIUVU&feature=g-logo";

    $parts = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($parts['query'], $query);

    print_r($query); // $query['v'] is what you want
?>
```

Comment: wonderful!! it does more than what i needed..Thanks a tonne

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is use of parse_url function.
[check this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

and then use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

```
print_r(parse_url('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N22qGmYIUVU&feature=g-logo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("~/watch\?v=(.*?)&~i", $uri, $matches);
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP 5.4 you can use Array Dereferencing:

```
parse_str(parse_url("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N22qGmYIUVU&feature=g-logo")["query"],$arr);
echo $arr["v"];
```